# IIS - list subwebs and the app pools they are in?

Tags: c#, iis-6, application-pool

I have an IIS 6.0 website with very many subwebs and several application pools.

I would like help establishing which app pool each of the subwebs is in using c#.

I have looked at the `DirectoryServices` namespace but still not sure of what to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a peek at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607175/how-to-get-applications-associated-with-a-application-pool-in-iis7) I realise this is for IIS7 but may be worth a try

```
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
    foreach (Site site in manager.Sites)
    {
        foreach (Application app in site.Applications)
        {

            if (app.ApplicationPoolName.ToString() == AppPoolName)
            {
                 string appname = app.Path;
            }
        }
    }
```