# How to know the Site is in which ApplicationPools

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, application-pool

I use the codes below to get the ApplicationPools and sites ,but how can i know the site is in which applicationpool

```
        var serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("127.0.0.1");
        var appPools = serverManager.ApplicationPools;
        var site= serverManager.Sites;
        Console.WriteLine("Sites:");
        foreach (var st in site)
            Console.WriteLine(st.Name);
        Console.WriteLine( );


        Console.WriteLine("Pools:");
        foreach (var ap in appPools)
            Console.WriteLine(ap.Name);
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607175/how-to-get-applications-associated-with-a-application-pool-in-iis7

Comment: @Amit ,thanks. It's right , maybe i use the different keys to search, it's not appeared just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ApplicationPoolName` you can know the name of the application pool that the application is assigned to
See [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.application.applicationpoolname(v=vs.90).aspx)

to display the app pool name on your web page you can simply use the below snippet code.

```
 <% Request.ServerVariables("APP_POOL_ID") %>
```

And you can also get `PoolName` as following below:

```
string appPoolName = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["APP_POOL_ID"];
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(appPoolName))
    appPoolName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_POOL_ID", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

To get IIS Server Variables take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx).

[This](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Jan/17/Programmatically-listing-getting-and-setting-Application-Pools) is also can be useful for programmatically listing, getting and setting Application Pools.

Comment: Post some code, how to do it. Link only answers are not good answers !

Comment: @mybirthname Ok, thank you for your advice I will edit.

Comment: Thanks ,the Application.ApplicationPoolName is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A site specifies the default application pool for applications. Each application can be changed to use another application pool if the default is inadequate.Use the following to obtain the site's and application's application pool:

```
var sites = new ServerManager().Sites;
foreach (var site in sites) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName);

    foreach (var application in site.Applications)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(application.ApplicationPoolName);
    }
}
```